# Loading resource from within project

Tags: java, maven, file, dependencies

I have a main project which has dependencies on multiple other projects.
Each project can have a folder called "images" under src/main/resources.
How could I make sure that every project loads its own images, not the ones from other projects?

What I've tried is this:

```
URL dirURL = this.getClass().getResource("/images/");
(new File(dirURL.toURI())).list()
```

The problem is that the program loads the first directory called "images" found in the classpath. If I have the projects "loaderA" and "loaderB", no matter where would the code above reside, it would always be read from project "loaderA".

How could I avoid this?

Comment: Resources are not files.  You cannot treat them like directories.  Some workarounds exist, but they are not reliable.  Your best option is to include a plain text resource that lists all the available images in your application.

Comment: @VGR That would work as well. How can I make sure that I don't have the same issues with that file as well(being read from the wrong project)?

Comment: Resources belong in packages.  This is why, if you pass a string to getResource which does not start with a slash, the default behavior of getResource is to look in the same package as the Class object.

Comment: @VGR And is there a way to ensure package names won't collide and get me in the same situation? As you probably imagine, I'm not in full control of all the projects/packages here. Sorry if it sounds like a dumb question.

Comment: If the projects aren’t under your control, you can set the classpath so the desired library comes first.  Another option is reading from all the projects, using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResources(resourcePath)`, but that won’t give you the ability to reliably discern which project each resource came from.  (You could examine each URL directly, but do you really want to rely on that?)